# See the list of the files in an external storage

Tags: java, android, list, storage, external

I wanted to see all the files I have in my external storage, I have this library that display the text to the user, but when I'm using it to show the sub files, it says something like :
`(Ljava.File;@` 
  How do I get it to show the name of the actual files to the user? Also, how can I show the name for a specific folder to the user? say file #3?

```
File[] files = myDir.listFiles();
UIHelper.displayText(this, R.id.textView1, files.toString());
```

Comment: Of course it is showing "Ljava.File;@", you are calling toString on a File Array. Is UIHelper  a class of your own?

Comment: How do you display the array I guess?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checl if sdcard is mounted or not.

```
 if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
       ///mounted
}
```

Get the path of sd card

```
 File dir= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Then call

```
  walkdir(dir);

 ArrayList<String> filepath= new ArrayList<String>();//contains list of all files ending with 

public void walkdir(File dir) {
 File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

if (listFile != null) {
 for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

 if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {// if its a directory need to get the files under that directory
  walkdir(listFile[i]);
} else {// add path of  files to your arraylist for later use

  //Do what ever u want
  filepath.add( listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

 }
 }  
}    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the code for printing list of files and folders from ExternalStorage

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
        File f = new File(path);        
        File file[] = f.listFiles();
        Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
        }
```

Don't forget to put below permission in you android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive method to scan all your SD card:

```
String sdCardState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
if( !sdCardState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED ) ) {
    //displayMessage("No SD Card.");
    return;
} else {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    lookForFilesAndDirectories(root);
}

// lookForFilesAndDirectories() method:

public void lookForFilesAndDirectories(File file) {
    if( file.isDirectory() ) {
        String[] filesAndDirectories = dir.list();
        for( String fileOrDirectory : filesAndDirectories) {
            File f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileOrDirectory);
            lookForFilesAndDirectories(f);
        } 
    } else {
        doSomethingWithFile(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this recursive method. Two  minor errors to fix in the code - dir should be file